# Kivy-- Image as Button

Tags: kivy

I am just beginner in kivy and object oriented programming.

I have been practicing this code as a combination of the tutorials here:

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior  
from kivy.uix.image import Image  
from kivy.lang import Builder  
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout  

Builder.load_string("""  
<ImageButton>:  
    FloatLayout:  
        Image:  
            source:'resizedA.png'  
            size_hint: .2, .2  
""")  

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior,FloatLayout, Image):  
    def on_press(self):  
        print ('pressed')


class The_AssignmentApp(App):  
    def build(self):  
        return ImageButton()  

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    The_AssignmentApp().run()
```

My question is, why is that even if I press the other parts of the screen(not the image), the app still considers the whole scree as a button?

Pardon my ignorance here, I would really want to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior,FloatLayout, Image):
```

Don't inherit from multiple widgets (in this case FloatLayout and Image), this will lead to some weird bugs.

As for your specific problem, the ButtonBehavior is a parent class of the ImageButton which is the root widget and fills the screen. For this reason, the whole screen *is* a button, though you clearly intended otherwise.

Is the following more like what you wanted? You can also just use a FloatLayout instead of creating the new RootWidget class, I just did this to fit with what you already wrote.

```
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior  
from kivy.uix.image import Image  
from kivy.lang import Builder  
from kivy.app import App  
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout  

class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):  
    def on_press(self):  
        print ('pressed')

Builder.load_string("""  
<RootWidget>:  
    ImageButton:  
        source:'resizedA.png'  
        size_hint: .2, .2  
""")  

class The_AssignmentApp(App):  
    def build(self):  
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    The_AssignmentApp().run()
```

Comment: I didn't understand how this could be used to fire an arbitrary function but this page of the documentation (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html) did make it clear. You simply have to add a class `ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image): pass`. Then you can use `ImageButton(source="PATH/TO/IMAGE", on_press=some_function())` to let the image act as a Button.